# pyalgotrade VWAP calcuation using yahoo historical data seems to be incorrect

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

I have just started with pyalgotrade,  using a modified sample code I got online that is using *VWAP ( volume adjusted average )* calculation,   as well as software's own method of acquiring  yahoo historical data,  I have noted the output *VWAP* calculation seems to be erroneous since yahoo adjusts its volume while the software tool assumes that volume is unadjusted.

Here is the code. Note the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uguvb.png) produced after execution and note the discontinuation  in *VWAP* calculation.  I compared Nasdaq data with yahoos that it has loaded and noted that Yahoo's volume is adjusted although it is not stated as adjusted.  I did set the flag to use adjusted data but the software does not use it for VWAP calculation as I believe  it assumes that volume is unadjusted.

I would appreciate if someone would identify a method by which I could correct the problem.  A method that I could use to override its own VWAP calculation would be fine.  Also I don't know how to report the error to the providers either since I am new to this.

```
 from pyalgotrade import strategy
 from pyalgotrade.barfeed import yahoofeed
 from pyalgotrade import plotter
 from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance
 from pyalgotrade.technical import vwap  #Volume Weighted Average Price

 import os

 class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
def __init__(self, feed, instrument, vwapWindowSize):



    strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)
    self.__instrument = instrument
    self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)     #   use adjusted close

    self.__vwap = vwap.VWAP(feed[instrument], vwapWindowSize )           # ,useTypicalPrice=True)

def getVWAPDS(self):

  return self.__vwap

def onBars(self, bars):

    vwap = self.__vwap[-1]
    if vwap == None:
        return

    shares = self.getBroker().getShares(self.__instrument)

                   #priceAdj = bars[self.__instrument].getAdjClose()
    price = bars[self.__instrument].getClose()
    notional = shares * price
    if price < vwap * 0.995 and notional > 0:
        self.marketOrder(self.__instrument, -100)
    elif price > vwap * 1.005 and notional < 1000000:
        self.marketOrder(self.__instrument, 100) 


def main(plot):
instrument = "aapl"
vwapWindowSize = 5

# Download the bars.
feed = yahoofinance.build_feed([instrument], 2011, 2016, "./data",)

myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, instrument, vwapWindowSize)

if plot:
   plt = plotter.StrategyPlotter(myStrategy, True, False, True)
plt.getInstrumentSubplot(instrument).addDataSeries("vwap", myStrategy.getVWAPDS())

myStrategy.run()
print "Result: %.2f" % myStrategy.getResult()

if plot:
    plt.plot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be fixed in the next version. Thanks for reporting this.